# Text is not aligned on the button

Tags: css

it has a button that will be used to open a content. Then when it is opened, the button text is changed to "-" and when it closes to "+".

I can't use icons!

Anyway, the "-" or "x", are not aligned on the button. I've used flex display, tested several things and I can't, someone help me please

[image]
[image]
[image]

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", (event) => {
  let button = event.target;
  if (button.innerText == "-") {
    button.innerText = "+";
  } else {
    button.innerText = "-";
  }
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {}

#btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 40px;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 600;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <button id="btn">
            x
        </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to add a width property.

```css
.btn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 40px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn">+</button>
<br/>
<button class="btn">−</button>
<br/>
<button class="btn">×</button>
```

Notes:

- The minus symbol is not the dash `-`, and the close symbol is also not `X` since they will be misaligned. Copy the symbol from the above code directly.

Symbol references

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus_and_minus_signs
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_mark

PS: Some code that is not in use in the answer have been removed from the snippet copied from question.

Comment: with "+" it looks right, but with "-" or "x" it is not centered

Comment: I have modified the answer to add extra variant. The padding method would fail so I have removed it from the answer. You might need to adjust the font size according to your needs.

Comment: It would be great if you could mark the answer as accepted, and upvote if it solved the issue. It would help future researchers find the answer faster.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion:

```css
button {
  background-color: red;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0 5px 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-indent: 3px; /* for perfect horizontal centering, with some fonts */
}
```

```html
<button>+</button>
<button>−</button>
<button>×</button>
```